# How to prevent page from losing tab selection, on page index change?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to display some tabs, and within each tab I also use a panel. within the panel I have placed an asp.net 4.5 GridView control with paging. Now, two things, when I change page, the whole page redraws, I lose the current position of my tab, and the page jumps to the top of the screen.

When I visit the previous tab, then page has indeed changed. I've seen lots of examples of capturing the tab using Jquery, but as yet, nothing to handle this issue.

my code is as follows:

```
   <div id="tabContainer">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#msgDate" data-toggle="tab">Message Date</a></li>
            <li><a href="#msgDateCurrency" data-toggle="tab">Message Date Currency</a></li>
        </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="msgDate">
                <div id="pnlMsgDateCurrency" class="panel panel-default">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning"><p>select view to see more information, or search to narrow the table</p></div>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="navbar-form navbar-right"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
                    </div>
                <!-- Table -->
                <div class="table"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="msgDateCurrency">
                <div id="pnlDateCurrency" class="panel panel-default">
                <!-- Default panel contents -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning"><p>select view to see more information, or search to narrow the table</p></div>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="navbar-form navbar-right"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
                    </div>
                <!-- Table -->
                <div class="table"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

for clarity, i've left out the grids, but they live in the table section.

So, how do i remain on the same tab, and prevent the page from jumping to the top, on page index change, or any post back for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid view is Jumping because when you change page it causes a post back and re-draws the whole page. so what is needed here in my opinion. try to use JavaScript for Paging and send ajax call to retrieve Page data to avoid page post back.

Comment: do you have any examples, links to people who have done it this way.

Comment: here is a good tutorial how it works.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33401/Ajax-Enabled-Gridview-using-JavaScript-in-ASP-NET

Comment: another good example 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/717350/ASP-NET-jQuery-Template-Grid-with-Paging-Sorting-a

Comment: So the first link is over 4 years old, so not sure i'd go that route to be honest. I note that the second example, uses asmx pages, i'm assuming then that we can't do this using webmethods?

I'll try and work through the second example though

Comment: this will be great source to read out the problem and it's solution you are facing http://forums.asp.net/t/1594409.aspx

Comment: i posted above links for you to just get started. Ajax is fantastic i think you start exploring it. You will do it with Web Methods using Ajax.

Comment: now look at this link this is the thing you should go with http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx